# two controllers with same params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, controller

i have 2 actions

```
public ActionResult FilesAdd(int id)
    {
        FillParentMenuDDL(id);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FilesAdd(int id)
    {
        //some logic...
        FillParentMenuDDL(id);
        return View();
    }
```

but it is error because of same parameters, but i need only one parameter. first i call page /action/id and then i submit it for example with id and uploaded file, but i access to file using request.files[0]. so what the solution with controllers and same parameters? i see only declare FilesAdd(int? id) in one controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an (unused) form parameter to the POST action. That will make the method signatures different.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FilesAdd(int id, FormCollection form)
{
    //some logic...
    FillParentMenuDDL(id);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Since he uploads one file, `HttpPostedFileBase name` parameter would be more appropriate.

Comment: This feels a bit hackish to me to add a redundant parameter that is never used.

Answer (score 3):

.Net MVC has an [ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) for this purpose. Rename your second action to something like FilesAddPost and then use `ActionNameAttribute("FilesAdd")`

```
public ActionResult FilesAdd(int id)
{
    FillParentMenuDDL(id);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("FilesAdd")]
public ActionResult FilesAddPost(int id)
{
    //some logic...
    FillParentMenuDDL(id);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the action of the submitted form, it doesn't have to go to the same action.

```
// Works under MVC 2.0 
<% using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post)) { %> 
// code
<% } %>
```